# What happens when I omit the brackets when trying to catch multiple exceptions?

Tags: python, exception

I just tried writing this:

```
try:
    # do something
except ValueError, IndexError:
    # do something else
```

And then got very confused when my program still threw an `IndexError` because I thought I was catching it.

If it doesn't catch the `IndexError`, what exactly does this code do? It doesn't seem to be a syntax error.

Comment: @Ralph: Oops. Good catch. That's what I meant :) Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because this mistake/problem is so common, the syntax changes for Python3. You code would be equivalent to

```
try:
    # do something
except (ValueError, ) as IndexError:
    # do something else
```

You would have seen that this is obviously wrong.

The new syntax works back as far as Python2.6

This works ok

```
try:
    # do something
except (ValueError, IndexError):
    # do something else
```

but often you want to do something with the exception, so you can write

```
try:
    # do something
except (ValueError, IndexError) as e:
    # do something with e
```

Comment: So wait.. it catches a `ValueError`, puts it in a 1-tuple and gives it the name IndexError? i.e., to get the ValueError I'd have to use `IndexError[0]`? Would that even work? Is IndexError then redefined from a type to the exception instance for the duration of the scope, or what?

Comment: @Mark, no - it's like `except <tuple of exceptions to catch> as <varible to store the specific exception in>:` In this example `e` would be either a `ValueError` or an `IndexError`

Comment: Right. Was confusing myself. Well that clarifies it enough for me :)

Answer (score 3):

It catches `ValueError`s, and assigns the caught exception to the name `IndexError`. You want this:

```
except (ValueError, IndexError):
```